# Symbol.Iterator - pass argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a problem with JavaScript code.

How Can I make that piece of code parameterized? I mean change 10 to variable which I can pass as an argument.

```
function createGenerator() {
var _state = 0;
return {
    next() {
        if (_state < 10) {
            return { value: _state++ };
        } else {
            return { done: true };
        }
    }
  }
}
var iterable = {
   [Symbol.iterator] : createGenerator
};
for (var f of iterable) {
   console.log(f)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it in as an argument and then `bind` your `createGenerator` function.

i.e.

```js
function createGenerator(num) {
var _state = 0;
return {
    next() {
        if (_state < num) {
            return { value: _state++ };
        } else {
            return { done: true };
        }
    }
  }
}
var iterable = {
   [Symbol.iterator] : createGenerator.bind(this,10)
};
for (var f of iterable) {
   console.log(f)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [partial application](https://medium.com/javascript-inside/currying-partial-application-f1365d5fad3f) - the outer function receives a number and returns the actual iterator that now has access to the number in the closure:

```js
function createGenerator(n) {
  return function() {
    var _state = 0;
    return {
      next() {
        if (_state < n) {
            return { value: _state++ };
        } else {
            return { done: true };
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


var iterable = {
  [Symbol.iterator]: createGenerator(5)
};
for (var f of iterable) {
  console.log(f)
}
```